# can bodyparser type take an array or wildcard

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

At the moment, I am having to do this for certain requests to parse specific requests:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/x-amz-json-1.1' }));
```

I would like to open this out to regular json also but the docs do not mention how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but according to [body-parser documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#type) it supports array and wildcards.

Quote from docs:

> The type option is used to determine what media type the middleware will parse. This option can be a string, array of strings, or a function. If not a function, type option is passed directly to the [type-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-is#readme) library and this can be an extension name (like json), a mime type (like application/json), or a mime type with a wildcard (like */* or */json). If a function, the type option is called as fn(req) and the request is parsed if it returns a truthy value. Defaults to application/json.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that it is working!
`app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*' }));` works for both `--header "Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1"` and `--header "Content-Type: application/json"`